# No way to access UICollectionView supplementary views from view controller?

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview

I have `UICollectionView` with a series of cells, and for each cell, some hidden annotations. The annotations are only meant to be shown when the the associated item is selected. So I added the following chunk of code to my controller's `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method:

```
WESpan *span = self.selectedSpan;
for (UIView *view in self.collectionView.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass: [AnchorCell class]]) {
        view.hidden = ((AnchorCell*)view).anchor.span != span;
    }
}
```

This works... but it seems ugly to me that I have to do the loop over all `subviews`, doing an `isKindOfClass:` check. Is there not a better way to do this? Something more idiomatic?

I wish there was an analog to the `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method, so I could fetch just the ones correlated with the appropriate index and hide/unhide them.

Answer (score 0):

`collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` ?

If you want to update a value in the supplementaryView you could always update your model and then reload the section of the collectionView.

```
[collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]];
```

Comment: Isn't that method what the data source delegate actually implements to manufacture one on demand for the `UICollectionView`. I don't want to send a message that's just going to deque and configure a new one... I want to access the one the UICollectionView has, which my delegate created with that method.